# RxJS - Conditional Concat and merge objects from response

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs, observable

I'm currently developing an ionic 5 app and I've 2 observables, they returns 2 arrays of different object types.
I want to mix some properties of the objects in a single one in a new type of object, but I only want to make the second call to the server if the first one returns values.

Example:

```
obs1$: Observable<{id: string, name: string, active: boolean}[]>;
obs2$: Observable<{id: string, location: Location, year: date}[]>;

newObs$: Observable<{id: string, name: string, year: date}[]>;
```

I want:

1. Call `obs1$`
2. If `obs1$` returns values then call `obs2$`, else returns `[]`
3. When `obs2$` returns values, return an array of objects mapping results of both observables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added some interfaces to make the code easier to read. I'm assuming here that your first observable returns an empty array when there is no values. If it returns `null` instead, you might want to remove `.length` in the `switchMap`.

The following code works just fine.

```
interface First {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  active: boolean;
}
interface Second {
  id: string;
  location: Location;
  year: Date;
}
interface Result {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  year: Date;
}

...
const first$: Observable<First[]>;    // Make sure it's initialized
const second$: Observable<Second[]>;  // Make sure it's initialized
...

const result$: Observable<Result[]> = first$.pipe(
  switchMap(firstArray => !firstArray.length
    ? of([])
    : second$.pipe(
        map(secondArray => firstArray
          .filter(a => secondArray.some(b => a.id === b.id))
          .map(a => ({ first: a, second: secondArray.find(b => a.id === b.id) }))
          .map(values => ({...values.first, year: values.second.year }))
        )
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are in a class. You can do something like this. But make sure you initialize your observables before mapping it.

```
  obs1$: Observable<{ id: string; name: string; active: boolean }[]>; 
  obs2$: Observable<{ id: string; location: Location; year: Date }[]>;

  newObs$ = this.obs1$.pipe(
    switchMap((item) => {
      const emptyArray: { id: string; name: string; year: Date }[] = [];
      return item? this.obs2$.pipe(
            map((item2) => {
              const others = item2.map((ent2) => {
                const index = item.findIndex(ent1 => ent1.id === ent2.id)
                let name = ''

                if(index !== -1){
                  name = item[index].name
                }
                const id = ent2.id;
                const year = ent2.year;
                return {name, id, year}
              });

              return others
            }),
          )
        : of(emptyArray);
    }),
  );
```